# Indexing in a paper

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, index-notation

Why to use the expression $\Bbb{1}\{j < m\}$ rather than just $1$? What am I missing?

Best regards

---

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.07770v3.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You missed that their definition of $[m]$ is actually $\{1, \dots, m\}$ which includes $m$ itself.